# WP admin bar not working in front end

Tags: wordpress

My admin bar is not showing on the frontend of my site.

1. It is set to display on the profile
2. Tried deactivating and activating all plugins
3. footer.php is fine
4. logged off and cleared the cache

Still no progress, can someone pls help.. I'm very new to blogging and have very little knowledge of programming. Thanks.

Comment: jus show us the demo video so that it can be very helpful for us to help you

Comment: install a different theme, id imagine get_footer is not being called or its set to display none, etc. Its not going to be more complicated than that

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. My admin bar has returned on posts but not on the pages.. :O

Answer (score 1):

1) check your function.php if this line is present

```
show_admin_bar( false );
```

2) if this is not present then try to add this in your function.php

```
show_admin_bar( true);
```